# How can I put this two statements into one statement?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I put this two statements into one singel statement. They work something like in a mirror.
I am trying to make the code look better and simple.
Any help is very appreciated.

```
           $('#q_login_dialog #menu-register').click(function() {

                    $('#q_login_dialog #menu-login').removeClass('q_dialog_panel_item_active');
                    $('#q_login_dialog #menu-register').addClass('q_dialog_panel_item_active');
                    $('#q_dialog_login input[type!=hidden]').val('');
                    $('#q_dialog_reset input[type!=hidden]').val('');
                    $('#q_dialog_login').hide();    
                    $('#q_dialog_reset').hide();                                    
                    $('#q_dialog_register').show();
                    $('#q_dialog_register input[name=email]').focus();
                    $('#q_dialog_login input').blur();
                    $('#q_dialog_login span').html('');
                    what = 'register';                              
                });

            $('#q_login_dialog #menu-login').click(function() {

                    $('#q_login_dialog #menu-register').removeClass('q_dialog_panel_item_active');
                    $('#q_login_dialog #menu-login').addClass('q_dialog_panel_item_active');
                    $('#q_dialog_register input[type!=hidden]').val('');
                    $('#q_dialog_reset input[type!=hidden]').val('');   
                    $('#q_dialog_register').hide();
                    $('#q_dialog_reset').hide();                
                    $('#q_dialog_login').show();
                    $('#q_dialog_login input[name=email]').focus();
                    $('#q_dialog_register input').blur();
                    $('#q_dialog_register span').html('');  
                    what = 'login';                     
                });
```

Comment: Inside the event handler, you can access the clicked element with `this`. For the rest, it would be easier if you'd show your HTML as well. Generally, use classes so that you can perform the same operation on multiple elements more easily.

Comment: You could just make one new function that does all of those things, save for any  differences in code.

Comment: Also let it be known that if you EVER have two ID selectors in one statement (like this: "#q_login_dialog #menu-register") you are doing things wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference between the two seems to be the use of `register` vs. `login`, which should be fairly easy to parameterize:

```
function makeClickHandler(type, subtype) {
    return function() {
        $('#q_login_dialog #menu-' + subtype)
                .removeClass('q_dialog_panel_item_active');
        $(this).addClass('q_dialog_panel_item_active');
        $('#q_dialog_' + subtype + ' input[type!=hidden]').val('');
        $('#q_dialog_reset input[type!=hidden]').val('');
        $('#q_dialog_' + subtype).hide();   
        $('#q_dialog_reset').hide();                                   
        $('#q_dialog_' + type).show();
        $('#q_dialog_' + type + ' input[name=email]').focus();
        $('#q_dialog_' + subtype + 'input').blur();
        $('#q_dialog_' + subtype + 'span').html('');
        what = type;
    }
}

$('#q_login_dialog #menu-register').click(makeClickHandler("register", "login"));
$('#q_login_dialog #menu-login').click(makeClickHandler("login", "register"));
```

My eyes could be missing another difference, but I think that's it (and, if not, you should see the general idea).

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a variable function and a closure:

```
var my_fct = function (action1, action2) {
    // here comes the closure
    return function() {
        $('#q_login_dialog #menu-'+action2).removeClass('q_dialog_panel_item_active');
        $('#q_login_dialog #menu-'+action1).addClass('q_dialog_panel_item_active');
        $('#q_dialog_'+action2+' input[type!=hidden]').val('');
        $('#q_dialog_reset input[type!=hidden]').val('');   
        $('#q_dialog_'+action2).hide();
        $('#q_dialog_reset').hide();                
        $('#q_dialog_'+action1).show();
        $('#q_dialog_'+action1+' input[name=email]').focus();
        $('#q_dialog_'+action2+' input').blur();
        $('#q_dialog_'+action2+' span').html('');  
        what = action1;                     
    };
};

$('#q_login_dialog #menu-register').click( my_fct('register', 'login') );
$('#q_login_dialog #menu-login').click( my_fct('login', 'register') );
```